# Python _winreg folder

Tags: python, regedit, winreg

I am currently trying to use python to search through registry entries using _winreg. This is my code:

```
from _winreg import *
import getpass

compName = raw_input("What is the name of the PC you wish to get a list of?: ")
currentUser = getpass.getuser()
filePath = "C:\\Users\\" + currentUser + "\\Desktop\\" + compName + "_Install_Programs.txt"

aReg = ConnectRegistry(compName,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData")
file = open(filePath, "w")
for i in range(1024):
    try:
        asubkey_name=EnumKey(aKey,i)
        asubkey=OpenKey(aKey,asubkey_name)
        val=QueryValueEx(asubkey, "DisplayName")
        val_disp = val[0]
        val_str = val_disp.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        if "KB" not in val_str:   
                file.write(val_str)
                file.write("\n")
    except EnvironmentError:
        pass
file.close()
```

However it will not search any subfolders of folders in there. For example it contains a folder called S-1-5-18 and then beneath that are 3 other folders called Components, Patches and Products. How do I get _winreg to go through all these folders and their following folders to find all keys with a "DisplayName" name value?

Looked at the documentation but couldn't see anything listed. It may be that the explanation isn't as clear as I think it is

EDIT

OK so I realised I wasn't drilling down to the folders so with this code I am getting the right access of the folders:

```
for i in range(1024):
try:
    asubkey_name=EnumKey(aKey,i)
    asubkey=OpenKey(aKey,asubkey_name)
    for j in range(1024):
        asubkey_name2=EnumKey(asubkey,j)
        if asubkey_name2 == "Products":
            asubkey2 = OpenKey(asubkey, asubkey_name2)
            for k in range(1024):
                asubkey_name3=EnumKey(asubkey2, k)
                asubkey3=OpenKey(asubkey2, asubkey_name3)
                print asubkey3
                for l in range(1024):
                    asubkey_name4=EnumKey(asubkey3, l)
                    print asubkey_name4
                    asubkey4 = OpenKey(asubkey3, asubkey_name4)
except EnvironmentError:
    pass
```

and my output shows the following:

```
<PyHKEY:0x000001E8>
Features
<PyHKEY:0x000001F0>
InstallProperties
<PyHKEY:0x000001F4>
Patches
<PyHKEY:0x000001EC>
Usage
<PyHKEY:0x000001D8>
<PyHKEY:0x000001E4>
Features
<PyHKEY:0x000001EC>
InstallProperties
<PyHKEY:0x000001F0>
Patches
<PyHKEY:0x000001E8>
Usage
<PyHKEY:0x000001D8>
```

So I know it has reached those folders. But when I add to the code to search for "DisplayName" like so:

```
for i in range(1024):
try:
    asubkey_name=EnumKey(aKey,i)
    asubkey=OpenKey(aKey,asubkey_name)
    for j in range(1024):
        asubkey_name2=EnumKey(asubkey,j)
        if asubkey_name2 == "Products":
            asubkey2 = OpenKey(asubkey, asubkey_name2)
            for k in range(1024):
                asubkey_name3=EnumKey(asubkey2, k)
                asubkey3=OpenKey(asubkey2, asubkey_name3)
                print asubkey3
                for l in range(1024):
                    asubkey_name4=EnumKey(asubkey3, l)
                    print asubkey_name4
                    asubkey4 = OpenKey(asubkey3, asubkey_name4)
                    val=QueryValueEx(asubkey4, "DisplayName")
                    print val
                    val_disp = val[0]
                    val_str = val_disp.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
                    file.write(val_str)
                    file.write("\n")
except EnvironmentError:
    pass
```

This is my output:

```
<PyHKEY:0x000001E8>
Features
<PyHKEY:0x000001E4>
Features
```

It's like it has lost the folders or isn't accessing them the same way. It's probably a simple solution but looking at it, I just can't see what's wrong here

Comment: Answer should be Encryption. Those are most probably encrypted.

Comment: They aren't though because I can point to the folder and obtain the information but it will only search one level of subfolder, not subfolders of subfolders if that makes sense?

Comment: That's because you are always accessing just one level below the same key. try doing it recursively.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. See my answer below based on your advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

After much investigating, I have found a solution. It may not be the prettiest but it works. I am open to suggestions on how to improve it, but here is my code for those who run into the same problem as me:

```
from _winreg import *

compName = raw_input("What is the name of the PC you wish to get a list of?: ")

aReg = ConnectRegistry(compName,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData")

for i in range(1024):
    try:
        asubkey_name=EnumKey(aKey,i)
        asubkey=OpenKey(aKey,asubkey_name)
        for j in range(1024):
            asubkey_name2=EnumKey(asubkey,j)
            if asubkey_name2=="Products":
                asubkey2 = OpenKey(asubkey, asubkey_name2)
                for k in range(1024):
                    asubkey_name3=EnumKey(asubkey2, k)
                    asubkey3 = OpenKey(asubkey2, asubkey_name3)
                    for l in range(4):
                        asubkey_name4=EnumKey(asubkey3,l)
                        if asubkey_name4=="InstallProperties":
                            asubkey4=OpenKey(asubkey3, asubkey_name4)
                            try:
                                dn=QueryValueEx(asubkey4, "DisplayName")
                                dn_Val = dn[0]
                                dn_Str = dn_Val.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
                                vn=QueryValueEx(asubkey4, "DisplayVersion")
                                vn_Val = vn[0]
                                vn_Str = vn_Val.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
                                pn=QueryValueEx(asubkey4, "Publisher")
                                pn_Val = pn[0]
                                pn_Str = pn_Val.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
                                print "Name: " + dn_Str
                                print "Version: " + vn_Str
                                print "Publisher: " + pn_Str + "\n"
                            except EnvironmentError:
                                pass

    except EnvironmentError:
        pass
```

This allows me to drill down and get the information required. Now I know that the use of try and except statements may be better utilised but for now this is the output it gives me (and what I was after!)

```
    What is the name of the PC you wish to get a list of?:

    Name: Microsoft Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies
    Version: 12.0.4518.1014
    Publisher: Microsoft Corporation

    Name: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2007
    Version: 12.0.6612.1000
    Publisher: Microsoft Corporation

    Name: Microsoft Office InfoPath MUI (English) 2007
    Version: 12.0.6612.1000
    Publisher: Microsoft Corporation

    ...............
```

I hope this helps